# How to Get attachments Associated with artifacts in SourceForge Enterprise Edition

Tags: sourceforge

We are using SourceForge Enterprise Edition 4.4 in one of our project.

My question is, in CollabNet SFEE (SourceForge Enterprise Edition 4.4), how will we get attachments associated with an Artifacts Using SFEE SOAP API?

We have made our own .net 2.0 client. We are not using .net SDK provided by Collabnet,

Answer (score 1):

If you commit with a message you can add "[artf1000]" (where artf1000 is your artifact number) to the beginning or end of your commit message. Then it will associate to that artifact you can also do this with documents using doc1000, to get the id of the item you can use the URL it is what is after the http://sfeeserver/sf/go/.

Documents and artifacts are the only item I have used this for so I am not sure about other types of links, but I would imagine anything that has a /go/ID could be referenced by the ID.

ie:

- http://sfeeserver/sf/go/artf1000
- http://sfeeserver/sf/go/doc1000

Edited to add:
I have seemingly successfully tried this with releases, tasks, and discussions as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can cheat a little bit and have a look at the scripts from SFEE. Log into your SFEE via SSH and take a look at the following script:

```
/usr/local/sourceforge/sourceforge_home/integration/post-commit.py
```

Maybe it helps...